# Insert record using view

Tags: mysql, view, insert-into

MySQL Workbench gives me an error on the following;

```
CREATE VIEW `view1` AS
insert into *tablename* (col1, col2, ...)
values (5, 'Jones Insurance', ...);
```

Is it possible to insert a record into a table using a view? The first column is an auto_increment field.

Any help much appreciated.

If I just try and do the insert that works fine.

Comment: Do you want to create VIEW and insert record? or you want to insert records into table from already created VIEW?

Comment: I want to create a view that inserts the record. As soon as I type insert I get a red x next to the line. I can't execute the view so that it shows up in the views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will work fine, and for Workbench specific problems,always put some value in rows created and then you will get an empty row.